# RJ45 Female Crimp Connector

Tags: connector

Where can I find a female RJ45 connector that can be crimped to another cable rather than being soldered to a PCB or installed in a wall or plastic enclosure?

Something like this: http://www.pcpartscollection.com/rjcrmatofeca.html

While we're at it, I'd love to find female RJ11 and RJ12 connectors with the same property.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One solution is a female-to-female coupler:

[http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-R6D011-Female-Inline-Coupler/dp/B00006HTTE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00006HTTE)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

@msutherl I wouldn't exactly call what you found in the local electronics store a crimp connector. Technically that would be a punch down connection. This wouldn't have the same strain resistance that true crimped on connector would have.

Comment: 'Cruch' connector, ok. I agree, and a crimp connector would be preferable to the punch connector.